# TemplateBinding to DependencyProperty on a custom control not working

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

Currently, I'm working on a simple custom button that uses user supplied images as a background for the pressed and normal states. I've a lot of buttons so I decided to write a custom button and implement two properties for the pressed and normal states' pictures.

Here is the code I'm using

```
public partial class ThemeableButton : Button
{
    public ThemeableButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty PressedContentBackgroundSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                    "PressedContentBackgroundSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ThemeableButton), null);
    public ImageSource PressedContentBackgroundSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(PressedContentBackgroundSourceProperty); }
        set
        {
            (value as BitmapImage).CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation; 
            SetValue(PressedContentBackgroundSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty NormalContentBackgroundSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("NormalContentBackgroundSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ThemeableButton), null);

    public ImageSource NormalContentBackgroundSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(NormalContentBackgroundSourceProperty); }
        set
        {
            (value as BitmapImage).CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation;
            SetValue(NormalContentBackgroundSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote the style for this button as follows

```
        <Style x:Key="ThemeableButtonTemplate" TargetType="MJbox_UIComponents_Controls:ThemeableButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="MJbox_UIComponents_Controls:ThemeableButton">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{TemplateBinding NormalContentBackgroundSource}">
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{TemplateBinding PressedContentBackgroundSource}">
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0">
                            <Image x:Name="ButtonBackground" Stretch="None" Source="{TemplateBinding NormalContentBackgroundSource}"/>
                        </Border>       
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I tried a simple example

```
<Controls:ThemeableButton Style="{StaticResource ThemeableButtonTemplate}" x:Name="btnDidntNeedIt" NormalContentBackgroundSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DefaultTheme}, Path=DidntHaveButtonUnselected}"
                                   PressedContentBackgroundSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DefaultTheme}, Path=DidntHaveButtonSelected}"
         />
```

but the image is not showing, I tried by removing the TemplateBinding from the style and replaced it with the relative source to the image file and it worked fine. I just don't wanna create a customized style for each button on the app. Any possible workaround?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I have encountered this before, TemplateBinding does not work for custom dependency properties on controls. See these related questions:

[issues with template binding and binding of custom component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598978/issues-with-template-binding-and-binding-of-custom-component)

[TemplateBinding does not work in certain cases(when using TranslateTransform)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346594/templatebinding-does-not-work-in-certain-caseswhen-using-translatetransform)

I have always used this instead:

```
{Binding MyProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}
```

It is semantically the same as TemplateBinding, and can also support value converters etc ...

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me too. I wish that TemplateBinding just worked and that some of the mystery and arbitrariness was dispelled.

Comment: "...TemplateBinding does not work for custom dependency properties on controls[.]" It works for me. `<Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding FillBrush}" />` in my custom control's `ControlTemplate` fills the `Rectangle` with my `FillBrush` custom dependency property, even showing that property in VS's property sheet and filling it with whatever I set it to during design time. Maybe that's something new since 2011? Anyway, it works fine now. (But watch out for animating to things that aren't `Freezeable`s. You still can't do that.)

Comment: To be more specific (at the risk of SO's bots grousing at me for extended discussions in comments), `TemplateBinding` won't work on the properties of `Freezeable`s. As far as I can tell, it fails silently. Your solution certainly applies in those cases.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on .net 4.7.2.  Did they close this loophole?