# How is TemplateBinding working in UserControl Template?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, controltemplate, templatebinding

I am new one to create UserControl and now I am trying to customize the UserControl Template as below:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.PieButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Loaded="OnLoaded">
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Path Name="path" Stroke="Aqua" StrokeThickness="3">
                <Path.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{TemplateBinding Fill}" />
                </Path.Fill>
                <Path.Data>
                ......
</UserControl>
```

At the same time I have create the dependencyproperty in back-end code:

```
public partial class PieButton : UserControl
{
    public PieButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }



    public Color Fill
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(FillProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FillProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FillProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Fill", typeof(Color), typeof(PieButton));
    ......
```

I want to use `TemplateBinding` in XAML to bind `Fill` property of my PieButton to fill the path object. The Visual Studio Designer warns me that "the Fill property is not accessible or recognized".

Based on my understanding, the `TemplateBinding` find the property name from the element that apply this ControlTemplate, which should be `PieControl` here, but why the `Fill` Property cannot access here?

BTW,

I test the following binding, and it can work for me

```
Color="Binding Fill,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}"
```

But I still think the TemplateBinding should be able to work under this scenario, so please point out my fault here. Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [TemplateBinding to DependencyProperty on a custom control is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656737/templatebinding-to-dependencyproperty-on-a-custom-control-is-not-working), 
TemplateBinding does not work for custom dependency properties on controls.

As a solution it is suggested to use

`{Binding MyProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}`