# Is it possible to use compiled binding (x:Bind) with Relative Source, Templated Parent

Tags: dependency-properties, uwp, templatebinding, compiled-bindings

I'd like to do something like this is a Style:

```
Value="{x:Bind MyCustomDependencyProp, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```

Is that possible? Are there any performance benefits?

Using TemplateBinding does not seem to work, with a custom DependencyProperty as described elsewhere here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8657453

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RelativeSource (with x:Bind) is not supported, therefore this particular scenario won't be possible (at the moment, at least).

Using TemplateBinding or *standard* Binding to TemplatedParent (as you mentioned) are workarounds.

TemplateBinding is already [an optimized version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms742882(v=vs.100).aspx) of Binding so it shouldn't be that big of a deal according to this [Build 2015 session by Sam Spencer.](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-635)

Comment: Actually `RelativeSource` is supported, only `Mode=FindAncestor` is not.

Comment: @JustinXL Hmmm are you sure? https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/2558207/9658304/b64f98da-5248-11e5-897d-79c55c7765cf.png

Comment: @JustinXL of course :) but the question was about using x:Bind with RelativeSource TemplatedParent

Comment: @JustinXL yeah, I edited to make it clearer what I meant. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you both for great reply and comments!

Comment: @JasperHedegaardBojsen if it answered your question, don't forget to mark it as answer. :)