# Getting the top parent template custom DP in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a custom control that has a custom DP, this control has a style that define multiple layers of `ControlTemplate`s:

```
                <ControlTemplate>
                   <Button>
                     <Button.Template>
                      <ControlTemplate>
                        <!--I want to use the custom DP here-->
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=myCtrl, Path=SubTitle}"/>
                      </ControlTemplate>
                     </Button.Template>
                   </Button>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

in the control template of the button I want to use the custom DP `SubTitle`, in the current implementation I'm using the control Name, but this doesn't help abstracting the control style, and re-usability:
unfortunately I can't use :

```
Text="{TemplateBinding SubTitle}"
```

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8657453/6197785):

it's good but useful only to go up one level, i.e. it can be used within the button- the direct child of the base control template, I did this as a work around:

```
                    <ControlTemplate>
                       <Button Tag="{Binding SubTitle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                         <Button.Template>
                          <ControlTemplate>
                            <!--I want to use the custom DP here-->
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}"/>
                          </ControlTemplate>
                         </Button.Template>
                       </Button>
                    </ControlTemplate>
```

but it's not efficient, and can't handle more than one DP.
so is there a more efficient way to use a custom DP of the base control within its grandchildren.

and I will take this opportunity to ask for resources explaining in detail the whole subject of Binding expressions: `TemplateBinding`, `RelativeSource`, etc. and the strange use of properties like this (is this part of the Binding topic?):

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                    (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
```

Comment: For the second question, see [PropertyPath XAML Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/propertypath-xaml-syntax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType=MyCustomControlType>
  <Button>
    <Button.Template>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType=Button>

        <!--I want to use the custom DP here-->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SubTitle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=MyCustomControlType}}"/>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
  </Button>
</ControlTemplate>
```

> {Binding Path=SubTitle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=*MyCustomControlType*}}

will make the binding expression to look for the binding target by traversing the visual tree from child to parent (or from node to root) until the first element matches the type defined by the 'AncestorType' parameter. On this type the XAML parser will try to resolve the binding path.

Second question answer:

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].
```

This markup tells your animation which property to animate. Since the property is nested, you as always have to reference the target property by resolving its property path. 
You then use parentheses for type casting while walking down your type's property path.

Given that the target of the storyboard is extending a *Panel*, e.g. a *Grid*, your snippet would do the following:

1. `(Panel.Background)` - will downcast the 'Grid' to a 'Panel' and reference the Background property
2. `(GradientBrush.GradientStops)` - will cast the Background, which is a 'Brush' by declaration, to a 'GradientBrush' and references the 'GradientStops' property, which is a collection of type 'GradientStopCollection'.
3. `[1]` - this indexer references the second element in the 'GradienStopCollection' that was referenced in step 2. This element will be of type 'object'.
4. `(GradientStop.Color)` - will cast the element returned from step 3 from object to 'GradientStop' to reference the 'Color' property

Answer (score 1):

instead of `RelativeSource TemplatedParent` use RelativeSource with AncestorType to find element of specific type (`{x:Type ...}`) higher in visual tree. In case of nested ControlTemplates it should be the target type of outer ControlTemplate

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SubTitle, 
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyControl}, AncestorLevel=1}}"/>
```

Comment: @MohamedAhmed, in your question `<!--I want to use the custom DP here--><TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}"/>`. you don't say which custom DP you have. write `Path=CustomDPname`

Comment: sorry for the confusion, can you edit your question so I can  cancel my downvote, (may be change `Tag` to `SubTitle`)

Comment: it worth mentioning to use the custom control name, not the base control, so `local:MyControl` instead of `CheckBox`